# CSS Triangle Under Button

Tags: css

What I am trying to accomplish on `:hover`.

[image: triangle]

```
.nav li {
  margin: 12px 0 0 20px; padding: 0;
  color: #000; font-weight: 700;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav li+li:hover {
  background: #2f3343;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin: 0 -2px 0 20px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: none;
}

.nav .triangle {
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 10px 12.5px 0 12.5px;
border-color: #000000 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

I would like to put the triangle in the `:hover` but it's completely messed up. Do I need to set a specific height and add a position?

Comment: `<li><a href="#">Monthly</a></li>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

i create a new

```
.nav li {
  margin: 12px 0 0 20px; padding: 0;
  color: #000; font-weight: 700;
  display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
 position:relative;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.nav li:hover {
  background: #2f3343;

  border: none;
}

.nav li:hover:after {
    content:"";
border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
left: 50%;
bottom: -10px;
    margin-left:-10px;
border-width: 10px 12.5px 0 12.5px;
border-color: #000000 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4XVdY/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try the following css:

```
.arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #000;
    margin-left: 15px;
    display: none;
}
button:hover + .arrow {
    display: block;
}
```

I have made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/3KsSw/) similar to this.  Have a look and provide your comments.